# systemd not starting systemd.networkd.service

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, systemd-networkd

Why does systemd decide to not start Network Service?

Ubuntu 20.04
After booting into kernel 5.8, systemd.networkd.service is no longer started

```
systemctl status systemd-networkd.service
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-networkd.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/systemd-networkd.service.d
         └─override.conf
 Active: inactive (dead)
```

By looking in syslog, systemd[1] decides to not start systemd.networkd.service

```
egrep '^.{16}[^ ]* systemd[[]' /var/log/syslog
…
Jan 10 14:30:40 x systemd[1]: Reached target Network (Pre).
```

The next line is supposed to be:

```
Jan 10 09:02:36 x systemd[1]: Starting Network Service…
```

A get-around is:

```
systemctl enable systemd-networkd.service
```

Checking another system, that is not how it works. On the other system we have enabled-runtime:

```
systemctl status systemd-networkd.service
● systemd-networkd.service - Network Service
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-networkd.service; enabled-runtime; vendor preset: enabled)
```

Why does systemd decide to not start Network Service?

1/27/2021: `cat systemd-networkd`

```
[Unit]
Description=Network Service
Documentation=man:systemd-networkd.service(8)
ConditionCapability=CAP_NET_ADMIN
DefaultDependencies=no
# systemd-udevd.service can be dropped once tuntap is moved to netlink
After=systemd-udevd.service network-pre.target systemd-sysusers.service systemd-sysctl.service
Before=network.target multi-user.target shutdown.target
Conflicts=shutdown.target
Wants=network.target

[Service]
AmbientCapabilities=CAP_NET_ADMIN CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE CAP_NET_BROADCAST CAP_NET_RAW
CapabilityBoundingSet=CAP_NET_ADMIN CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE CAP_NET_BROADCAST CAP_NET_RAW
DeviceAllow=char-* rw
ExecStart=!!/lib/systemd/systemd-networkd
LockPersonality=yes
MemoryDenyWriteExecute=yes
NoNewPrivileges=yes
ProtectControlGroups=yes
ProtectHome=yes
ProtectKernelModules=yes
ProtectKernelLogs=yes
ProtectSystem=strict
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=0
RestrictAddressFamilies=AF_UNIX AF_NETLINK AF_INET AF_INET6 AF_PACKET AF_ALG
RestrictNamespaces=yes
RestrictRealtime=yes
RuntimeDirectory=systemd/netif
RuntimeDirectoryPreserve=yes
SystemCallArchitectures=native
SystemCallErrorNumber=EPERM
SystemCallFilter=@system-service
Type=notify
RestartKillSignal=SIGUSR2
User=systemd-network
WatchdogSec=3min

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Also=systemd-networkd.socket
Alias=dbus-org.freedesktop.network1.service
Also=systemd-networkd-wait-online.service
```

Comment: see systemctl cat systemd-networkd output above

Comment: The service is OK.

Comment: The cat output reflectes after enable. Why did systemd service stop starting networkd unless it was manually enabled with `systemctl enable systemd-networkd.service`?